# phpThumb - Prevent and avoid cropping – fit to maxwidth/maxheight?

Tags: php, image, phpthumb

I am fixing up a website that uses phpThumb to generate thumbnails. The documentation/readme is available [here](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/docs/phpthumb.readme.txt).

I am trying to resize the images so that they fit within 1200x1200 pixels, but maintain their aspect ratio and are not cropped.

However, it seems no matter what I do, the images are always cropping. I am trying these options to no avail:

```
"h" => 1200,
"w" => 1200,
"far" => "C"
```

I've left out the "zc" or 'Zoom Crop' function to try to avoid cropping, but no matter what, I keep getting a cropped image. Am I missing something? Or is phpThumb not capable of dynamically forcing the image to fit within a given square dimension?

**Note**
Unfortunately we are tied to using phpThumb over an alternative as the site/cms plugin makes use of it exclusively.

Comment: Try using another library, the timthumb, https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/

Comment: big note at bottom of his question....

Answer (score 0):

far = "Force Aspect Ratio" - so you are forcing 1200px by 1200px - remove that and it should work as expected.

Comment: I've actually tried it without *far* and it simply crops a 1200x1200 square.

Comment: then i cant help from the info you provided - the default for phpThumb is to not crop so something must be over-riding it, remove every setting other than width and height.